# Possible to avoid including whole standard header file because of one method?

Tags: c

I would like to call the "C" function

```
fabs(double);
```

numerous times in my program, but I don't want to include the whole header file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't hurt to include the whole file.
Not used stuff will not be compiled into your executable.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, you can manually prototype it. Just add

```
double fabs(double x);
```

to the top of your source file.

Answer (score 3):

you could declare the function yourself, but why would you want to avoid including the header file ?

Comment: I was afraid that functions I did not use would be compiled in, but apparently this is not an issue.

Comment: ah, ok. I thought you wanted to avoid including headers to speed up the compilation process, but math.h is not very big in general.